# Using a workflow to update fields also effected by workflows

Tags: custom-object, workflow, formula, approval-process

Afternoon all,

I have two custom objects (Child & Parent),

The Child is a questionnaire type that can be submitted to a customer (via email, its a visualforce page), they then approve it (when the questionnaire is submitted to client, it is locked same as an internal approval).

They then can click confirm or reject, which unlocks the record and updates the "status" picklist.

I am trying to display this "status" on the parent object, using workflow rules. 
Currently the workflow rule has the Object set as the Child, the field to update in the parent. The formula value is text.

The issue i am having is - if I change the "status" picklist value in the child manually it will update the field in the parent as per the workflow, however if the 3rd party update the field from the visualforce email they get sent (ie, confirm or reject!) it does not update as per the workflow rules.

Help please!!

Answer (score 1):

<del>If the 3rd party update uses a workflow field update to update the status value (e.g. as part of the approval process), make sure that that field update has the checkbox *'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change'* checked.</del>

Option 1) apex trigger to update the status on parent object

Option 2) (didn't test this) roll-up summary that counts the number of children with status 'x'. Then workflow on parent object that updates the status accordingly.

Comment: Hi Guy, This is not possible because we want the field in the Parent updated. When I set the checkbox i get an error message because it is only available at parent to child level. thnaks.

Comment: You are right. Updating my answer..

Comment: Hi Guy, many, many thanks for your quick replies, have got a bit caught up here, so will try your suggestion this evening and report back! Thanks again :)